# How access a generic class's subclass in csharp?

Tags: c#, generics, reference

I have a simple question in C#:

I have a class (Properties ) embedded inside a generic class (Box) as follows:

```
public class Box<E> where E : Box{
    public class Properties {
    }
}
```

How can I make a reference to the subclass (Properties) from an outer class?
I need something equivalent to this java statement:

```
Shape<?>.Properties prop = new Shape<?>.Properties();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it. You have to specify `E`.

`Shape<OneBox>.Properties` is different class then `Shape<AnotherBox>.Properties`

[C# Specification (10.3.8.5)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx)

> Every type declaration contained within a generic class declaration is
>   implicitly a generic type declaration. **When writing a reference to a
>   type nested within a generic type, the containing constructed type,
>   including its type arguments, must be named.**

Comment: oh I didnt know that ... so there are no wildcards in Csharp?

Comment: @Shatazone No. You can workaround this specifying `IProperties`, non-generic interface and use it in your methods/variables declaration, but you wan't be able to use it to instantiate an object of `Shape<>.Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. A classical solution, if `Properties` doesn't need `E`, is something like:

```
public class Box {
    // So that it can't be instantiated, or you could make the class abstract
    protected Box()
    {
    }

    public class Properties {
    }
}

public class Box<E> : Box {
}
```